# SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type in android

Tags: android, github, actionbarsherlock

Hi i have to develop android BBc news reader application from [BBC NEWS READER](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader)

Here i have to import these app from above link and run the app means i get the following error.how can i resolve these error ??? please help me

The error is :

SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type...i got the error on below line...

```
public class WidgetConfigActivity extends SherlockActivity {
ListView listView;
```

I have added library file also.

Comment: Have you added the `ActionBarSherlock` library?

Comment: no...whare i have to get these library..

Comment: [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: yes i get it zip file from here.no i ahve added my workspace these zip file afterthat import the app means no projext found error id display..so how can i add the ActionBarSherlock library in my bbc app...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Download ActionBarSherlock from [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).
- Unzip the downloaded file and import the project to Eclipse.
- Right-click on your project -> Properties
- In Android->Library section click Add
- If you added the ActionBarSherlock library correctly you can find it
  there.
- Add it your project

Checkout this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) on how to reference a library project in eclipse.

**EDIT:**

To remove the `android-support-library` dependancy error, remove the `android-support-v4.jar` file present in the **libs** section of your project.

The reason for the error is that `ActionBarSherlock` already has an `android-support-v4.jar` along with the library. So there arises a conflict between the two files

Comment: i got the below error:http://pastie.org/private/g1dqdvkgljds9lrjauigq      how can i clear above these error.

Comment: i have deleted the jar file from my libs filder in my project.now i have to run the app means am getting following error:02-07 11:41:03.997: E/AndroidRuntime(2589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 11:41:03.997: E/AndroidRuntime(2589): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
02-07 11:41:03.997: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):  SherlockFragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: The error may not vanish automatically. Click on the error. There you will get an option to add the necessary libraries.

Comment: i have to learn from http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/ here.now i got the solution.thanks for your help..