# SherlockActivity cannot be resolved be a type

Tags: android, listview

I'm getting below error message on below code

```
SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type
```

**Check My Code**

```
public class SocietyInfo extends SherlockActivity{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    EditText edt_society_name, edt_society_reg_no, edt_soceity_mob_no,et_society_register_user,et_society_app_passwd,edt_society_email_id,edt_society_email_passwd,edt_society_survay_no;
    EditText edt_society_pin,edt_society_city,edt_society_landmark,et_validity_date;
    Button btn_society_info_save,btn_society_passwd_save;
    EditText et_society_setting_passwd;
    int flag;
    Editor editor100;
    final SocietyInfo context = this;
    String validity_date;
    int a;
    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z]+\\.+[a-zA-Z]+";
    static SharedPreferences loc100;
    String cms_path;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  get().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add Event");
        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("Society Info");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_society_info);
        flag=getIntent().getIntExtra("flag",0);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+flag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        edt_society_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_society_name);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743700/sherlockactivity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-in-android)

Comment: `SherlockActivity` is deprecated and discontinued few years ago. You should not use it anymore. Use AppCompatActivity instaed. It has all features